# Why does C++ invoke a copy constructor when iterating a container?

Tags: c++, copy-constructor

```
void ParticleGeneratorController::generate() {
    for( unsigned i = 0; i < generators.size(); i++) {
        ParticleGenerator generator = *generators[i];
        generator.update();
    }
}
```

Seems to call a copy constructor or something, but I didn't define one. I only have an explicit default constructor.

https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/Waveform/blob/master/src/models/particle_generator.h

Given my above code, by test fails. https://github.com/ChrisLundquist/Waveform/blob/master/spec/controllers/particle_generator_controller_spec.cpp#L21

When written as

```
void ParticleGeneratorController::generate() {
    for( unsigned i = 0; i < generators.size(); i++) {
        generators[i]->update();
    }
}
```

The test passes.

Why is the copy constructor called in the first implementation? How is it generated by the compiler?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line causes the copy:

```
ParticleGenerator generator = *generators[i];
```

If no copy constructor (or assignment operator) is explicitly specified, the compiler automatically generates one. If you wish to prevent copying of an object you can declare, and not define, the copy constructor and assignment operator as `private`:

```
ParticleGenerator
{
public:

private:
    ParticleGenerator(const ParticleGenerator&);
    ParticleGenerator& operator=(const ParticleGenerator&);
};
```

Comment: Or with c++11 `delete`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Explicitly_defaulted_and_deleted_special_member_functions

Comment: @BoBTFish, ah yes, forgot all about that (and if I'm honest, have not had the chance to actually use it yet).

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new `ParticleGenerator` each time you do this:

```
ParticleGenerator generator = *generators[i];
```

This is a copy initialization, and, given that you didn't explicitly provide a copy constructor, the compiler-synthesized one is used.

Comment: @sepp2k I didn't want to go into [copy initialization](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/036.htm) for the sake of brevity.

Answer (score 0):

The following line does the copy:

```
ParticleGenerator generator = *generators[i];
```

If you don't define a copy constructor the compiler automatically does it for you. In order to disable that, you can declare the copy constructor as private and not implement it. Usually that should be done with the copy assignment operator as well.

If you want to avoid making a copy in your code, you can simply create a pointer instead. Write

```
ParticleGenerator * generator = generators[i];
generator->update();
```

into your loop instead. Or

```
generators[i]->update();
```

if you want to be really short-hand.